# No se puede acceder a una variable privada desde una vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, poo

Hola tengo que hacer una clase empleadoprogramador que herede de la clase base empleado y luego tengo que calcular el sueldo.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Empresa2.Models;

namespace Empresa2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        public ActionResult Programador()
        {
            EmpleadoProgramador emp1prog = new EmpleadoProgramador();
            emp1prog.Nombre = "Ezequiel";
            emp1prog.Apellido = "Perez";
            float sueldo1 = emp1prog.ObtenerSueldo();            
            sueldo1 = 15000;
            //CalcularSueldo("Adrian", "suarez",20);
           // emp1prog.ObtenerSueldo();
            return View(emp1prog);
        }


    }
}
```

Empleado.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Empresa2.Models
{
    public abstract class Empleado
    {
        public string Nombre { set; get; }
        public string Apellido { set; get; }
        public Empleado() { }

        public Empleado(string Nombre, string Apellido)
        {
            Nombre = this.Nombre;
            Apellido = this.Apellido;
        }

        /*  public abstract float CalcularSueldo();
          } */

    }
}
```

EmpleadoProgramador.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Empresa2.Models
{
    public class EmpleadoProgramador : Empleado
    {
        private float SueldoFijo { set; get; }


        public float ObtenerSueldo()
        {
            return SueldoFijo;
        }

        private EmpleadoProgramador(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas, float valorHora, float incentivo)
            : base(Nombre, Apellido)
        {

            valorHora = 50;
            incentivo = 5000;
            CalcularSueldo(Nombre, Apellido, horas, valorHora, incentivo);
        }



        public EmpleadoProgramador()
        {
        }

        private float CalcularSueldo(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas, float valorHora, float incentivo)
        {

            float Sueldo = (valorHora * horas) + incentivo;
            return Sueldo;
        }


    }
}
```

Programador.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Programador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Model.Nombre
        <br />
        @Model.Apellido
        <br />
        @Model.ObtenerSueldo()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo cuando quiero mostrar el sueldo, me lo muestra como cero, que está pasando?

Comment: Hola Andrés, veo algunos detalles en tu códugo, lo primero es que ambas clases se llaman `Empleado`, luego, una debe heredar de la otra, lo cual tampoco existe, otra es que en la clase *padre* `Empleado` no existe la definición del método `ObtenerSueldo()` y en la clase que hereden de ahí debe tener su implementación, en este caso la implementación deberá estar en la clase `EmpleadoProgramador`

Comment: estaba mal la codificació, ya la edité

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te muestra 0 porque nunca inicializas la propiedad SueldoFijo.

Por otro, lado, si ObtenerSueldo() solo regresa el valor de tu propiedad privada SuledoFijo, te sugiero mejor la crees como un propiedad:

```
    private float sueldoFijo;
    public float SueldoFijo
    {
        get { return sueldoFijo; }
        set { sueldoFijo = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad tiene bastantes errores de codificación. Intenta cambiar estos dos archivos de la siguiente manera:

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Empresa2.Models;

namespace Empresa2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        public ActionResult Programador()
        {
            EmpleadoProgramador emp1prog = new EmpleadoProgramador("Ezequiel", "Perez", 10, 1000, 500);            
            return View(emp1prog);
        }


    }
}
```

**EmpleadoProgramador.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Empresa2.Models
{
    public class EmpleadoProgramador : Empleado
    {
        private int _horas = 0;
        private float _valorHora = 0;
        private float _incentivo = 0;

        public float ObtenerSueldo()
        {
            return (_valorHora * _horas) + _incentivo;;
        }

        private EmpleadoProgramador(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas, float valorHora, float incentivo)
            : base(Nombre, Apellido)
        {
            _horas = horas;
            _valorHora = valorHora;
            _incentivo = incentivo;            
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que en ningún lugar asignas un valor a `SueldoFijo`.

Puedes solucionarlo, asignando un valor a `SueldoFijo` cuando calculas el sueldo del empleado:

```
private float CalcularSueldo(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas, float valorHora, float incentivo)
{
    SueldoFijo = (valorHora * horas) + incentivo;
    return SueldoFijo;
}
```